# WPF Event Aggregator - wait for previous execution to complete

Tags: c#, wpf, prism, eventaggregator

I am working on a WPF application using Prism. I am using EventAggregator to communicate between viewmodels.

```
public class PublisherViewModel
{
   _eventAggregator.GetEvent<RefreshEvent>().Publish("STOCKS");
}
```

```
public class SubscriberViewModel
{
    public SubscriberViewModel(IEventAggregator ea)
    {
        ea.GetEvent<RefreshEvent>().Subscribe(RefreshData);
    }

    void RefreshData(string category)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
                //Long Running Operation

                Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
                {
                     //Refresh UI
                });
        });
    }
}
```

*PublisherViewModel* can publish event one after another. However at a *SubscriberViewModel* as I have a long running *Task* and is not awaited (which I cannot) the second request coming from publisher start execution right away. At *SubscriberViewModel* I want to handle all incoming request such that they are executed one after another in the order which they arrive.

I am thinking to handle this using a queue based mechanism.

Could you please suggest me the best practice for the same.

Thanks!!

Update:-
I have used the below approach

```
public class BlockingQueue<T> wehre T : class
{
    private readonly BlockingCollection<JobQueueItem<T>> _jobs;
    public BlockingQueue(int upperBound)
    {
        _jobs = new BlockingCollection<JobQueueItem<T>>(upperBound);
        var thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(OnStart));
        thread.IsBackground = true;
        thread.Start();
    }

    public void Enqueue(T parameter, Func<T, Task> action)
    {
        _jobs.Add(new JobQueueItem<T> { Parameter = parameter, JobAction = action });
    }

    private void OnStart()
    {
        foreach (var job in _jobs.GetConsumingEnumerable(CancellationToken.None))
        {
            if (job != null && job.JobAction != null)
            {
                job.Action.Invoke(job.Parameter).Wait();
            }
        }
    }

    private class JobQueueItem<T>
    {
        internal T Parameter { get; set; }
        internal Func<T, Task> JobAction { get; set; }
    }
}
```

```
public class SubscriberViewModel
{
    BlockingQueue<RefreshEventArgs> RefreshQueue = new ...;

    //inside Subscribed method
    RefreshQueue.Enqueue(args, RefreshData);
}
```

Please suggest. Thanks!

Comment: why are you unable to await the task?

Comment: @Default, I was going to ask the same question

Comment: @Default because the nature of these events is to be fire and forget. Any synchronization or waiting must be done by the consumer.

Comment: it can still be fire, but if you want to synchronize you can't forget everything about it. You don't need to mark the method async, but you can still save the task in a variable, or setup some other synchronization (see for instance `TaskCompletionSource´). Would that work or is the code, how to say.. locked?

Comment: I think the statement "I cannot await the Task" seems to be misleading. I am invoking an action through an event aggregator, so the action at subscriber has to be fire and forget else it would block the UI thread. Even if I await the task, my problem statement remains the same. I need to queue up all the request from the publisher and execute them at subscriber one at a time in the order in which the request arrives. Hope it clears the doubt.

Comment: What was wrong with `_queue = new ActionBlock<Job>( job => job.Action.Invoke(job.Parameter) );` and `_queue.Post(newJob);`? This is tested and working and a lot more customizable than your self-made variant. And it's a lot less work, also, just think of the mass of tests you need for your class because of the inherent complexity and potential for race conditions and the like in this kind of code.

Answer (score 0):

> I am thinking to handle this using a queue based mechanism.

This is the way to go. Set up a queue (probably an asynchronous queue), push the events in the subscriber and consume them from a worker task.

[TPL Dataflow](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow/) is one option to do this: create an `ActionBlock<string>` from the handler and post the events to it as they come in.